# Power BI. Combine 2 legends in bar chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have 2 tables:

[This is the relationship between the tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dildb.png)

[This is the Channel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tu3h.png)

[This is the Feedback table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6SUl.png)

[This is the visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAgsM.png)

Basically, on the barchart, I am required to combine Fax and Mail together because Fax is kind of obselete. However, if I were to merge the two rows together, then the relationship link between the tables wouldn't work. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Calculated Column to the Channel Table:

```
Report Name = 
IF ( 
    Channel[Name] IN { "Mail", "Fax" },
    "Mail / Fax",
    Channel[Name]
)
```

Then use that `Report Name` field for your chart legend